# how add function beforeSend in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have quetion about jquery, how add function `beforesend & success`
this my code :

```js
$("body").on("click", "#br-submit-assets", function(e) {

  var form = $(this).parents("form");
  var btn = $(this);

  form.ajaxSubmit(function(ret) {

    $("#loadding").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');


    $(".career-notif").parent("div").remove();
    var html = generate_alert(ret.result.status, ret.result.msg);
    btn.parent("div").before(html);


  });

  return false;

});
```

It's work for me but I want display `#loading` before send data like :

```
beforeSend: function () {
     $('#loading').append('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
beforeSend: function () {
     $('#loading').show();
}
success : function(data){
      $('#loading').hide();
}
```

And in your HTML add a div like this

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none"><img src="images/loader.gif" /></div>
```

Comment: You should put this code in Ajax function and use this HTML tag after your body tag